# SHA256 Hashing with two blocks: Where should the hash of the first block be inputed?

Tags: hash, cryptography, sha256

I have just implemented an SHA256 generator, but am encountering problems for multiblock has. Could anyone help to clarify the problem, please?

For easy checking, we use this specific text input: "And to every beast of the earth, and to every fowl of th"

Since this is exactly 448 bits, it must be split into 2 blocks, according to the padding rule (length field is just too short by one bit).

My step by step outputs are as follows:

Original message in binary is: 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0

message length is: 448 bits

Padded complete message is: 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0

Message length after padding is: 1024 bits

Starting block 1 hash for partial message: 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Block length: 512

SHA256 hash value of Block 1 is: 2,1,8,2,5,A,3,D,F,3,1,C,E,E,3,9,3,6,A,D,A,F,C,3,6,0,F,8,0,F,9,8,8,0,C,5,8,D,2,F,F,E,C,3,4,4,A,8,2,9,D,F,6,8,2,F,2,5,D,F,6,D,C,D

Could anyone please clarify this two questions for me:

1. Is the hash number for the Block 1 correct?
2. If Block 1 hash is all correct and good, where should this hash number 21825A3D... be inputed when Block 2 hashing is about to start?

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that you use block code for the output. The output should be without all the comma's. If you are nice you could also wrap around at e.g. 80 characters and use an underscore between the different parts of the blocks (e.g. right before the padding with 1).

Comment: PS Many animals don't eat grass of even leaves and grass has "only" been around for 55 million years or so, which means that most animals that have lived never ate grass.

Comment: i wondered when choosing it if the passage would be recognizable (without google) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is the hash number for the Block 1 correct?

Yes. Congrats. It's not a number though; it is just a hash *value* as the binary doesn't represent a single number value.

> 2. If Block 1 hash is all correct and good, where should this hash number `21825A3D...` be inputed when Block 2 hashing is about to start?

There are these initial hash values, <strike>sometimes also called constants</strike>. They are named h0..h7 [in the pseudo-code of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Pseudocode). Your found intermediate hash should replace them. The h0..h7 is also the output of the final hash (unfortunately, as having no final operation on the hash allows for the length extension attacks).

Comment: Thank. you very much! That just solved my problem. Have a wonderful day.